# Iframe won't load content until devtools are opened

Tags: cefsharp

**Problem:**
I use CEFSharp to serve local content in a C# application.

In some cases I've got several iframes that should load different local URLs based on user actions.

I load content in those iframes using the Iframe.LoadUrl method. The URL is using the file schema.

In runtime, the application does not load the new url for the iframe until I open the devtools. When I do that, the iframe's contents are loaded perfectly and quickly.

This only happens once per iframe: After opening devtools, I can execute the same code and the iframe's contents are updated accordingly. I'm guessing the iframe's state is wrong somehow, but so far I haven't found any differences before/after opening devtools.

**Context:**
This application was running OK in CEFSharp 85.3. The library's version was upgraded to 101.0.

The code I'm working on is a plugin, and the initialization is managed by the main app, so I have little flexibility there. I could request changes if reasonable though.

Has anyone seen something like this before?

Comment: Check the log file for errors. Newer versions of chromium have much stricter file scheme security,  as such using the file scheme is not recommend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround for now, it seems to be working fine:

instead of doing:

```
frame.loadURL(url)
```

I'm using:

```
frame.Parent.ExecuteJavaScriptAsync("document.getElementById('" + frame.Name + "').src = '" + url + "'", "file:///");
```

I'm not really happy with my solution, but it seems to be working for now in my case.